# python: TypeError: Not implemented for this type

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

from the code:

```
import numpy
     :
print(numpy.isnan([1.,2.,3.,'A']))
```

I am wondering why it doesn't just return false? Since I just want to check if the array has any non-numeric value. Thanks!

Comment: How did you import `numpy`? Can you add some more of your code for a minimal example?

Comment: nothing fancy, just "import numpy" ... it is a simple testing code, the above is pretty much all for this example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `numpy.isnan` function only detects `NaN`s and only accepts floats (or arrays of floats to be more exact), the character 'A' is not an `NaN`, it's a character, its type is `str`; you would get the same error if you try `numpy.isnan('A')`. Your code only works for lists of the type `[1, 2, 3, numpy.nan]`:

```
print(numpy.isnan([1., 2., 3., numpy.nan]))
>>>[False False False True]
```

If only checking for `numpy.nan`s is your objective and you want to get a single boolean for whether the list contains a `numpy.nan` or not, you may want to use this instead:

```
print(numpy.isnan([1., 2., 3., numpy.nan]).any())
>>>True
print(numpy.isnan([1., 2., 3., 4.]).any())
>>>False
```

Now getting back to what you want (to detect if the list contains a non-numeric value like 'A'), you can do something like this:

```
def contains_non_numeric(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if any([isinstance(item, float), isinstance(item, int), isinstance(item, complex)]):
        #You can remove or add the types that you find to be acceptable in your list
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Trying this out, you'll get what you want:

```
contains_non_numeric([1, 2, 3, 'A'])
>>>True

contains_non_numeric([1, 2, 3])
>>>False
```

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining that it can't test the string:

```
In [167]: np.isnan([1,2,3,'A'])
...

TypeError: Not implemented for this type
In [168]: np.isnan('A')
...
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

`isnan` is not a test for non-numeric type.

> isnan(x[, out]): 
>   Test element-wise for NaN and return result as a boolean array.

Since you are testing a list (not an array), I'd suggest:

```
In [172]: try: [float(i) for i in [1.,2.,3.,'A']]
   .....: except ValueError:
   .....:     print('has a nonnumeric element')
   .....:     
has a nonnumeric element
```

Note what we get when we try to convert the list to an array:

```
In [173]: np.array([1.,2.,3.,'A'])
Out[173]: 
array(['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', 'A'], 
      dtype='<U3')
```

an array of strings.

Comment: There's a very sneaky issue in your solution, it will not identify `"42"` (i.e. a string of digits) as a nonnumeric, `float("42")` will return `42.0`...

Comment: Indeed; what does the OP have in mind when it comes to `non-numeric`? I have no objection to using an `isinstance` test if that suits the case better.

Comment: Re: "what does the OP have in mind when it comes to `non-numeric`?"- beats me... If only we lived in a world where the OP would explain exactly what they are after...